# Error: fatal: Fetched in submodule path 'repository_name', but it did not contain 'SHA-1'. Direct fetching of that commit failed

Tags: git, github, github-pages, git-submodules, github-pages-deploy-action

I'm trying to build & deploy my website through github pages but i keep getting these two errors in "jobs > build > checkout > fetching submodules" for one of my repositories. The other ones aren't facing any issues. Where's the ".gitmodules" file supposed to be located? I can't find it in any of my repositories.

```
  /usr/bin/git submodule sync --recursive
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 submodule update --init --force --depth=1 --recursive
  Error: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'repository_name' in .gitmodules
  Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

When i tried solving the problem by adding a ".gitmodules" file at the root of my repository, it resolved the old errors but also gave me some new errors:

```
  /usr/bin/git submodule sync --recursive
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 submodule update --init --force --depth=1 --recursive
  Submodule 'repository_name' (git://github.com/repository_name/repository_name/) registered for path 'repository_name'
  Cloning into '/home/runner/work/repository_name/repository_name/repository_name'...
  Error: fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 19bdc6feaae5bdaf8692f11939881191a791fd7e
  Error: fatal: Fetched in submodule path 'repository_name', but it did not contain 19bdc6feaae5bdaf8692f11939881191a791fd7e. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
  fatal: 
  Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

The result of "git submodule status" on my local machine is:

```
  -19bdc6feaae5bdaf8692f11939881191a791fd7e repository_name
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved when i removed another repository which i had accidentally embedded into my repository earlier.